# support.v4.ListFragment shows data in Android 3.0 but not in 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-fragmentactivity, android-listfragment, android-actionbar-compat

Why does the simple code below work in Android 3.0, but not in 2.3.3 ??? 
In 2.3.3, it shows only a blank screen.
There is no message in LogCat. 
Any help would be appreciated.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class TestListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter;

    private String[] data = {"One", "Two", "Three"};

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);

        setListAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
}
```

Regards,

**** EDIT

I found the cause. If the activity extends FragmentActivity, the code above works in 2.3.3, but if it extends ActionBarActivity it does not work.

Does someone know how to solve it ?

Comment: Please post layout.simple_list_item_1.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the workaround is jus not use the default android.R.id.content to show the fragment.
I just do this:
In the onCreate() of your activity(extends ActionBarActivity):

> setContentView(R.layout.whocares);
>   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.the_root_view,yourFragment).commit();